# How to use textarea as an insert parameter

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I am using a WYSIWYG chkeditor to allow people to submit text to a SQL Server database.

I am trying to capture their username and the code, however chkeditor will only work with textarea so I have this in my form:

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="description" rows="5" cols="15">Write message here </textarea>

<a runat="server" title="Manage your account">Written by: <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %></a>
```

My code-behind contains the following:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    MSG.InsertParameters("username").DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name

End Sub
```

It works for the username when submitted but I can't figure out how to get the textarea. I am pretty new at all of this.

My datasource is configured as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="MSG" runat="server" 
     ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:FCBL_DB %>" 
     InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [messageboard] ([message], [TS], [IP], [username]) VALUES (@message, @TS, @IP, @username)"  
     SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [messageboard]" 
     ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" 
     OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
     <InsertParameters>
         <asp:Parameter Name="message" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="TS" Type="DateTime" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="IP" Type="String" />
         <asp:Parameter Name="username" />
     </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `formfield` attribute in the fashion of `<asp:formparameter name="Phone"  formfield="PhoneBox" />`? (From the example at [SqlDataSource.InsertParameters Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insertparameters(v=vs.110).aspx).) (P.S. did you mean ckeditor rather than chkeditor?)

Comment: yes typo on my part.

Comment: I have not tried that I am looking at the link you have posted but I have never set anything up like that.  I use visual studio community and do very little coding by hand as this is just a hobby.  Where would I define that?

Comment: As you can see from the example at the link, it goes in the `<InsertParameters>` section. I'm off to do other stuff right now so I can't help further, but perhaps you could hunt down more information on Google etc.

Comment: `<textarea>` is rendered from `<asp:TextBox TextMode="Multiline" ...>`. So use this server control.

Comment: the issue I ran into was with ckeditor would not work with a textbox they use a textarea.

Comment: Understood but ckeditor only works with textarea